# Google search with textView from a button press in iOS

Tags: ios, textview, qr-code

I am customizing an open source QR Reader to take the text from a TextView and either do a Google search or open the text in a browser. The customer is adamant about using Google search only.

I have two buttons. "Google" and "Web". The code indicates how they work.

I was thinking of appending "http//www.google.com/search='" with "resultText.text'"
But I don't know the correct format on how to do that with a google search.

The code I have to do this thus far is:

```
- (IBAction)openBrowser :(id)sender
{
    if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"Google"]) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:resultText.text];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

}
    else if([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"Web"]){
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:resultText.text];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
}
```

I tried googling this, but as you can imagine the results were nothing close to what I was looking for. I kept getting Google/Apple search bar headlines from the recent news.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my own question after a more extensive search.

http://www.our-picks.com/archives/2007/01/30/google-search-urls-revealed-or-how-to-create-your-own-search-url/

Here is the code I added in:

```
if ([[sender currentTitle] isEqualToString:@"Google"]) {
NSMutableString *googleUrl = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"http//www.google.com/search?q="];
[googleUrl appendString:resultText.text];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:googleUrl];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

}